# Subset a dta.frame according to repeated colname

Tags: r

I have a big data.frame that looks like this:

```
   Col1      Col1    Col2      Col3    Col4     Col4
    sd      rt       yu       hg     e         po
    23      0.12     0.34     0.2    0.98      0.2
    vf      qw       we       mi     kl        jk
    0.21    0.33     0.1      0.234  0.76      0.54
```

I need to remove (and save in a second data.frame) all the columns with the same header. How can I do that? I'm new in R.

Comment: So you'd like to remove four columns in total (i. e. columns 1, 2, 5, 6) or just the second ones of those columns appearing twice (i. e. columns 2, 6)?

Comment: Hi flowla! I would like to remove col 1, 2, 5, 6. The real case consist of 15.000 total columns of which I have to remove columns with replicated col name as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should identify all column names that appear twice using `duplicated` (I would appreciate any suggestions that help to get rid of the doubled `duplicated` statement, though). Store these column indices in a numeric vector for further working steps.

```
# Data generation
data <- data.frame(rbind(c("sd", "rt", "yu", "hg", "e", "po"), 
                         c(23, .12, .34, .2, .98, .2), 
                         c("vf", "qw", "we", "mi", "kl", "jk"), 
                         c(.21, .33, .1, .234, .76, .54)))
names(data) <- c("Col1", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col4")

# Identify duplicated column names
dupl.cols.ff <- duplicated(names(data))
dupl.cols.fl <- duplicated(names(data), fromLast = TRUE)
dupl.cols <- sort(unique(c(which(dupl.cols.ff), which(dupl.cols.fl))))
```

Now, can build a new dataframe based on the identified columns and remove them from your initial dataframe.

```
# Build new dataframe with duplicated columns 
data2 <- data[,dupl.cols]
names(data2) <- names(data)[dupl.cols]
data2
  Col1 Col1 Col4 Col4
1   sd   rt    e   po
2   23 0.12 0.98  0.2
3   vf   qw   kl   jk
4 0.21 0.33 0.76 0.54

# Remove duplicated columns from initial dataframe
data <- data[,-dupl.cols]
data
  Col2  Col3
1   yu    hg
2 0.34   0.2
3   we    mi
4  0.1 0.234
```

Comment: `dupl.cols.ff <- names(data)[ names(data) %in% duplicated(names(data))]`